# Remote Desktop stopped working

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, desktop

I am running Windows Vista Business SP2 on my main PC connected to router by a cable and my wireless laptop runs Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. I installed additional Microsoft Office components and now Remote Desktop will not connect to the main PC.

With the computer name `Wilson-PC`, I get the error `Remote Desktop cannot find the computer Wilson-PC`.

When I use the IP `192.168.1.70` I get an error with the 3 following options: `Remote access not enabled`, `Remote computer turned off`, `Remote Computer not available on network`, however when I run ping in Command Prompt I get ping reply OK.

I have checked and Remote Access is Enabled and Firewall allows Remote access.

Here is `ipconfig`'s output

```
C:\Users\Wilson>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration 

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-spcific DNS Suffix = : gateway.2wire.net
Link-Local 1Pv6 Address..........= : fe80: :28a3:75a6:423c:3257x8
IPv4 Address...........................= : 217.41.5.240
Subnet Mask............................= : 255.255.255.224
Default Gateway......................= : 217.41.5.239 

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*6:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix.......:
IPv6 Address................................: 2001:5ef5:79fb:809:19eb:26d6:fa0f
Link-LOcal IPv6 Address..............: fe00::19eb:26d6:fa0f%9
Default Gateway..........................:

Tunnel Adapter Local Area Connection* 7:

Media Stare................................... :Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix........: gateway.2wire.net

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix ......: gateway.2wire.net
IPv6 Address..........................,,,,,,,,,: 2002:d929:5f0::d929;5f0
Default Gateway.............................: 2002:c058:6301:c058:6301
```

Can anyone give a suggestion please?

Comment: Routing and Remote Access firewall rule? That is not the same as Remote Desktop